# Why does powershell insist 18 is less than 9?

Tags: powershell

[image: Screenshot]

Why does this come up true?
(The Get-Date is set to 18 Right now...)
Is it maybe something with the way Get-Date formats the number?
I'm stumped....

Comment: I don't know powershell, but that looks like it's doing a string comparison, not a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a few have said already, you're doing a string comparison rather than a number comparison

```
$Time = Get-Date -Format %H
$Time.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

In order to do what you want, you can cast your `$Time` to a number

```
[int]$Time -lt 9 
#or with a little trick 
+$Time -lt 9
```

Answer (score 5):

`Get-Date -Format` returns a string.

That means you're comparing the 2-letter *string* "18" with 9.

The `-lt` operator will (just like any other comparison operator in PowerShell), upon seeing a string as the left hand argument, attempt to convert the right-hand argument to a string as well, so the comparison is effectively:

```
"18" -lt "9"
```

Since "1" comes before "9" in an alphabetical sense, the comparison returns `$true`